# overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant

Tags: c++, covariance, virtual-functions, return-type, object-slicing

Ah, SO came back just in time.

I am getting a strange error:

```
 'B::blah': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'A::blah'
```

Here is the code causing the problem:

```
class A {
public:
    class Inner { };

    virtual Inner blah() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    class Inner2 : public Inner { };

    Inner2 blah() {
        return Inner2();
    }
};
```

I looked up the error, and according to [a page I found on the Microsoft website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240862), one of the ways types can be covariant is if:

> the class in the return type of B::f is the same class as the class in the return type of D::f or, is an unambiguous direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of D::f and is accessible in D

Is that not the case with `Inner` and `Inner2`? I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 if it matters.

---

OK, so thanks to John I learned that only pointers and references can be covariant. Why is that? A Derived can be cast to a Base, so why don't virtual functions with return types that are derived from the same thing just cast the return type to the one of the base class? In my example, it seems like it would make sense to have `(A*(new B))->blah()` return a `Inner` that is really an `Inner2` that has been cast up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Only pointers and references can be covariant.

Comment: John, will you read my comment on Sorens answer and see if you can answer that as well?

Comment: The reason you can't covariantly return value types is that those types can have different size. For example A::Inner may be 4 bytes long and B::Inner2 8 bytes long. And yes, you can't return reference to local object. But this is somehow different problem than asked. Bottom line: you will need to return pointer and somehow manage its lifetime.

Comment: you can return a derived class from a normal function whose signature says it returns a Base, so why can't you do that for virtual functions? Like, `Base test() { return Derived(); }` works.

Comment: @Seth: That's called *slicing*, because `Base` has a copy constructor `Base(const Base &)` which (unfortunately) has to accept a `const Derived &`, but this is almost guaranteed not to be what you want.

Comment: In case of `Base test() { return Derived(); }`, first you create `Derived` then create `Base` using copy constructor. If you won't provide user constructor it will just discard extra `Derived` members. You can't change return type for value object, because if caller is expecting 4-bytes long `Base` then receiving 8-byte long `Derived` would make serious mess around stack.

Comment: @Kerrek I know of slicing, and in this case it is exactly what I want. Slicing is better than completely keeping me from doing something. And still, that doesn't answer why it doesn't work.

Comment: If you're fine with slicing then just return `A::Inner` in derived class.

Comment: @John no, I need callers who know that a particular pointer is a `Derived*` to get a `Derived*` back, and classes who only know it's a `Base*` to get a `Base*` back.

Comment: @Seth: the question is where the slicing is done and the calling conventions. Consider that if you call through a reference to `base` then the caller will allocate space for the function to return a `inner` object, and there will be no more space than that. If the final overrider were to write a `inner2` it would write *beyond* the space allocated, and that would be undefined behavior. Note that this is different with John's last comment, where the slicing is performed inside the virtual function, and only the `inner` subobject will be written.

Comment: @David that makes sense, but like you said, why isn't it made so that the function does the slicing? You'd think C++ could know what type was expected to be returned and which one was actually being returned.

Comment: @Seth: The compiler, when processing the function does not know who is going to make the call, it does not know whether the static type at the place of call is `base` or `derived`, and it has to provide a single definition. If you want the function to do the slicing, then return a `inner` object, but that will not let you return different things depending on the static type at the place of call. Alternatively you can provide two functions, a non-virtual that returns `inner2` and the virtual that returns `inner` (forwards the call to the new function, slices and returns it)

Comment: @David thanks, that answers my question. And yeah, I had gone with making two functions, one virtual and one not, I just wish it were possible to do it the other way.

Comment: @Seth: You should revisit your design. Depending on slicing is a strong code smell, and it might just be that you are taking the wrong approach to solve the actual problem. If you want polymorphic behavior you should do with references and pointers, not values. I don't think the language should allow that, as I have not ever seen a good use case for the feature, and the compiler will catch errors from people not understanding the difference between value and reference semantics. Slicing is confusing enough as it is to allow more valid cases in the language.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas "_the question is where the slicing is done_" Somewhere. Not in the calling code obviously. "_and the calling conventions._" Which convention? The one for Base or for Derived?

Comment: "_The reason you can't covariantly return value types is that those types can have different size._" Wrong. There is no reason. It's like that, period.

Comment: @curiousguy: If you want to believe there is no reason feel free. On the other hand, you can try to think on the calling conventions (take the Itanium C++ ABI as a good example) and try to think how to to implement dynamic dispatch allowing for covariant return of value types. Of course, you could design a completely different object model (the callee allocates the space in the stack and returns the object and size that was allocated), but that would not be the C++ object model (or philosophy, as there would be added costs for each call). Most design decisions have a justification.

Comment: @curiousguy: Regarding the previous comment (*the question is where the slicing is done*) I am not sure I made myself clear. If there is no covariant value return type, the function would slice on the return expression. In a previous comment Seth suggested that he'd rather have the object sliced (if the callee does not slice, the alternative is the slicing to happen in the caller), and there it cannot be safely done, as the reserved space is what it is (and it is reserved by the caller, that is the *calling convention* and it is not Base/Derived, it is platform/compiler).

Comment: @curiousguy: On a personal matter, I find that you tend to assert rather than reason. I think it would benefit everyone if rather than claiming something to be a fact (*There is no reason. It's like that, period*) you provided alternatives. I understand that if there is no reason for the design to be like it is, there will be viable alternatives. With that on the table it would be much easier to determine whether those alternatives are valid and thus there really is no reason, or whether the alternatives have worse flaws.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine that your example worked.

Consider the following code:

```
A *a = some_function();
A::Inner inner = a->blah();
```

If the dynamic type of `a` is B*, then `a->blah()` calls `a::B->blah()`, and returns a `B::Inner`.  This is then silently *sliced* into an instance of `A::Inner`.  In general, this (and any type of slicing) is not what you want.  I find this to be a good restriction.

Comment: In general, this (and any type of slicing) is allowed in C++.

Comment: @curiousguy Indeed it is, and it's nearly always a bug.

Answer (score 2):

If what you request would be allowed it would mean that a call to blah() via the base class must do a conversion from Inner2 to Inner... a cast is not possible since the caller is responsible for managing the returned object (since it is not returned by pointer/reference but by value) and will reserve space for it on the stack. So it can only handle Inner not Inner2 or whatever ancestor class.

So you then have an instance of Inner, not Inner2... So you don't get any advantage...

Answer (score 0):

> Why is that?

Simply because the ISO C++ standard committee ruled it that way!

There is no fundamental reason. It could be done differently, at the cost of a tiny additional compiler complexity.

Comment: It's not considered "tiny" in the domains where C++'s efficiency matters, and is fundamentally incompatible with how "by value" returns work.

Comment: @JimmyHartzell Efficiency of what?

Comment: @JimmyHartzell How is that "fundamentally incompatible with how "by value" returns work"?

Answer (score 0):

objects declared on the runtime stack must be known to the compiler at compile time:

```
void f(const A & a) {
   Inner inr = a.blah( );

}
```

inr must be of both static and dynamic type "Inner" (not "Inner2") to be allocated off the stack -- so if blah returned an Inner2 it would be used to construct an Inner and it's "2ness" would be lost (or sliced as K Dragon mentions).

Comment: "_it's "2ness" would be lost_" which seems to be the intent of the code writer here. When you declare an `Inner` instance, you get an `Inner` instance, not an `Inner2` instance. What is the problem here?

Comment: The code writer states in the question "return a Inner that is really an Inner2 that has been cast up."

Answer (score -1):

The `blah` method have to return A::Inner in all cases -- if you think of the reason it is quite simple.   A instance of B could easily be case to the base class A.   Now if anybody calls blah on A (the base class which object should it return?  Inner2 or Inner?

Comment: Like you said, a `B` can be cast to an `A`, but likewise an `Inner2` can be cast to an `Inner`. So when `blah` is called on a `B` which is cast to an `A`, it would return an `Inner2` cast to an `Inner`. Why doesn't it do that?

Comment: The return types cannot be different between the two -- you can simpy just make B instantiate a Inner2, but return it as a ref to Inner, and that would solve it as well -- I will update the answer to refects this.

Comment: no, I can't do that because that would be returning a reference to a local object.

Comment: -1. As soon as you use the result of `B::blah` you enter undefined behavior land.