# Cat is not covariant with Animal when overriding virtual method

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual

As I'm learning about the method overriding rules in C++, I've been reading about covariant types, which basically seems to be a fancy word for a sub-class or derived class (at least with respect to C++). I did some testing, and found that there was one surprising exception that I didn't understand. The following shows:

```
struct Animal {};
struct Cat : Animal{};

Cat gCat;

Animal* getAnimalPointer() { return &gCat; }  // Returning covariant type by pointer, OK
Animal& getAnimalReference() { return gCat; } // Returning covariant type reference, OK
Animal getAnimalCopy() { return gCat; }       // Returning covariant type by copy, OK
// All good

// Now testing virtual method overriding by using C++ feature of 
// allowing overriding virtual methods using covariant return types
struct AnimalShelter
{
    virtual Animal* getAnimalPointer() {};
    virtual Animal& getAnimalReference() {};
    virtual Animal getAnimalCopy() {}
};
struct CatShelter : AnimalShelter
{
    Cat* getAnimalPointer() override;       // Returning covariant type by pointer, OK
    Cat& getAnimalReference() override;     // Returning covariant type by reference, OK
    Cat getAnimalCopy() override;           // Returning covariant type by copy, fail
    /* Visual Studio error: return type is not identical to nor covariant with 
    return type "Animal" of overriden virtual function CatShelter::getAnimalCopy*/
};
```

Edit: Turns out only in the virtual case does C++ prevent you from returning a covariant type by copy, see Fire Lancer's excellent answer on possibly why. There is another question similar to this, where there is interesting discussion in the comments on whether the reason for this is that the caller doesn't know how much space to allocate for the return type in the case of a virtual call.

[overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969020/overriding-virtual-function-return-type-differs-and-is-not-covariant?rq=1)

Comment: You have object slicing with `Animal getAnimalCopy() { return Cat(); }`.

Comment: Yeah I thought it would be less clutter that way.

Comment: "But it seems when returning from functions it's fine" the problem with C++ is that not everything that seems fine actually is fine ;)

Comment: It seems that returning from functions, pointers, references and copies you're allowed to return covariant types, but with virtual method overriding you're only allowed to return pointers and references. Strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Covariant return types in C++ mean the overriding return type must be references or pointers.

Value types can have different sizes, even if the they share a common base. Where as a pointer or reference is normally identical, or at most a byte shift (virtual or multiple inheritance).
But converting a value type might result in slicing because of converting from a larger type to a smaller type via a copy (even if the base type defines a copy constructor or operator, they still often slice, because there is nowhere to store any extra fields the derived class added).

e.g. lets say this was allowed and I had two types `A` and `B` I wanted to use as covariant returns from `X` and `Y`.

```
struct A
{
    int x, y;
};
struct B : A
{
    int c;
};



class X
{
public:
    virtual A get_a();
};
class Y : public X
{
public:
    B get_a()override;
}
```

The problem here is that when using a reference to `X` which might actually be a `Y` I can do this:

```
X *x = new Y();
A a = x->get_a();
```

But by calling `get_a` on a `Y` instance that actually returns a `B`, it must convert the `B` to an `A` implicitly, but this would "slice" off my `B::c` member, which could leave it in an invalid state (espiecally if `A` had any virtual functions, and those functions expected `B::c` which is now "outside" the object).

And in the general case, neither the programmer or the compiler could tell this might happen at the `A a = x->get_a()` line because `X` could be dervied by anything (maybe even outside the compiler potential knowledge, e.g. in a seperate DLL!).

In the non-virtual case, the compiler and programmer can tell its happening, so allthough C++ does allow slicing, there is at least knowledge that it is happening and likely a compiler warning.

```
class X
{
public:
    A get_a();
};
class Y : public X
{
public:
    B get_a(); // Not an override!
}
X *x = new Y();
A a = x->get_a(); // still called X::get_a, no slice ever!


Y *y = new Y();
A a = y->get_a(); // calls Y::get_a, which slices, but the compiler and programmer can tell that from static typing.
```

Comment: Not just the overriding type but the return type in the base class too.

Comment: Interestingly, there was a debate on the other question about this topic about whether the reason C++ prevents it in the case of virtual method is that the caller doesn't know how much space to allocate for the return type in a virtual call.